# LibGDX: Where is the X-/Y-Coordinate of a circle?

Tags: java, libgdx

I´m wondering how a circle is positioned. For example the X-/Y-Coordinates of an rectangle are in the bottom left corner of itself. But how does it work with a circle?
~Henri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rectangle` position(X and Y coordinate) defined by bottom-left corner of itself.

But in case of [`Circle`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Circle.html) there is no corner or any such parameter. Circle having center(X and Y coordinate) and radius.

If we construct a circle with default constructor

```
Circle circle=new Circle();
```

In this case x,y and radius all are zero, so circle center is at at bottom-left of the screen with radius zero.

Answer (score 1):

X/Y coordinates of circle is it's center.

Here is one of circle's constuctors.

```
/** Constructs a new circle with the given X and Y coordinates and the given radius.
 * 
 * @param x X coordinate
 * @param y Y coordinate
 * @param radius The radius of the circle */
public Circle (float x, float y, float radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}
```